# Does the most known image of Long-finned pilot whale depict one with the melon inflated or not inflated?

Tags: zoology

The most common image of the Long-finned pilot whale shows a bulbous head. Some may think this is merely an inflated melon:
[image]

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Pilot_whale_spyhop.jpg/330px-Pilot_whale_spyhop.jpg

...but images of an inflated melon in Long-finned pilot whales show what seems a lateral position:
[image]
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wwhandbook/sidebar-images/_sidebarPromo/PIFSC_20170901_S104_G-0384_PAO.jpg

...so does anyone knowledgeable in LFPWs know if it's an inflated melon or a big brain in top picture?

After all, they have the highest neocortical count:

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnana.2014.00132/full